# Best practice for refactoring methods

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

I am wondering what would be the the best practice for refactoring code that looks like this:

Where should the exit criteria should be set and what is the best practice

```
    private static bool Foo()
    {
        bool result = false;

        if (DoMehod1())
        {
            if (DoMehod2())
            {
                if (DoMethod3())
                {
                    result = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DoMethod3 Failed");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DoMethod2 Failed");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DoMethod1 Failed");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It could be helpful if you explained what the `DoMethod` methods actually do, and why they are returning error codes via boolean results, rather than throwing exceptions when they fail to "do method".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best structure for that code without changing what it does is this:

```
private static bool Foo()
{
    if (!DoMethod1())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoMethod1 Failed");
        return false;
    }

    if (!DoMethod2())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoMethod2 Failed");
        return false;
    }

    if (!DoMethod3())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("DoMethod3 Failed");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This does not output all results

Comment: I don't know what "does not output all results" means, but this is functionally identical to the code in the post.

Comment: @UfukHacıoğulları: How does this not output all of the results? If `DoMethod1` returned `true` and `DoMethod2` returned `false` the only line executed before the final return would be `Console.WriteLine("DoMethod2 Failed.");`.

Comment: +1; This is not a bad way to do it *with the given code*.  Though I contend (see my answer) that the functions *probably* have the wrong signature to begin with.  Error handling shouldn't be cooperative by default - it should be forced through exceptions, because otherwise unhandled errors will accidentally go unnoticed.  It's hard to tell for this case, though, because the function names `DoMethod` have no meaning.  They're verbs, which implies they should throw exceptions when they fail to "do method", but I don't know if they should be or not...

Comment: I agree that the code is probably wrong, but trying to read the intention and fix the design of an contextless method named `Foo` calling functions named `DoMehod1` is sort of firing into the dark.

Comment: +1 for early returns, aka mid-function returns.  In another time, another language family, this was seen as a bad practice (because it was); in today's languages it is best, because it makes our code much easier to comprehend.

Comment: Although this is the best way to do this, programmers have an unholy obsession with leveraging early returns. They act like this is going to bring millions of dollars into the company. And this question is feeding the fire !!

Answer (score 4):

I contend that the best practice should be:

```
private static void Foo()
{
    DoMehod1();
    DoMehod2();
    DoMehod3();
}

// ...

try
{
    Foo();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    throw;
}
```

And throw exceptions when you can't keep the promise that `DoMethod()` implies by having a verb-based name.

If you absolutely don't want to throw exceptions, use [the method suggested by mquander](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8417168/232593), and rename your methods to `TryDoMethod1`, etc.

If you need to ensure that they all run (which you don't do in your original code), you can try one of these:

- Build a list of methods to call (as delegates), and loop over those methods with a `try`/`catch` built into the loop, and [use an `AggregateException` to combine them all the sub-exceptions for one final `throw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx).
- Do something similar using [the Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx).

Comment: I suppose this could work, but I'm generally not a fan of using exceptions to control program flow. Especially if there was another method being executed in response to where the failure occurred.

Comment: @Joshua: The original design abuses control flow to implement error handling.  They don't need the control flow if they do their error handling correctly (using exceptions).  The example is completely hypothetical, though, so it is hard to tell by their name whether those methods should throw exceptions, or should be expected to fail silently/cooperatively.  I contend that their signature is wrong, because I rarely code that way.  So I erred on the side I prefer to err :)

Answer (score 3):

Read this classic article on "Arrow Code" http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/flattening-arrow-code.html to learn how to "flatten it" by returning the errors as soon as possible.

The Code Complete section on "Arrow Code" can be found at: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ArrowAntiPattern

@mquander's answer is ideal.

The point is to get out of the habit of a single point of exit, this would be needed in code where you would have to manage your memory because you would need a single place to de-allocate it (similar to how you could use `finally` block). Since .NET manages your memory you can leave the method as soon as possible without worrying about memory leaks and making your method more readable.

Comment: I think exceptions should be used, unless there's a compelling reason to have errors returned via code (ala `Try` methods), so I don't think mquander's solution is necessarily ideal.  But the OP code is pretty opaque, so it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1):

What would be wrong with:

```
return (DoMethod1() && DoMethod2() && DoMethod3())
```

...in the calling code and do away with the Foo method altogether

Comment: Presumably the `Console.WriteLines` express some side effect that needs to happen differently depending on whether `DoMethod1` or `DoMethod2` or `DoMethod3` failed, which is hard to express in a one-liner like this.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's a fair comment. It would also ALWAYS evaluate all 3 - DoMethod3 could hide a lot of work which you didn't _want_ to run everytime too, but I thought I'd throw a minimalist suggestion out there :)

Comment: Actually, no. `&&` short-circuits in C#, so if `DoMethod1` failed, `DoMethod2` and `DoMethod3` would never run.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the #1 goal should be code that is easily understandable.  It's hard to say what is the best structure for the code without knowing the underlying functionality and having things named appropriately.

There is no one-size-fits-all best code structure IMHO, it all depends on the story you're trying to tell with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) pattern here.